# Cross dromain posting data in ie9 from http server to https server

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9, postmessage, xdomainrequest

I have user entered data that is being posted to different domain and a different protocol. After doing some reading, I discovered that Microsoft's `XDomainRequest` object doesn't allow for cross-origin interactions (Different protocols, ports, #7 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx).

I'm doing a standard CORS AJAX call for FF, Safari, and Chrome (which works), and I've been trying to use the XDomainRequest object for IE9.

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
  var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
  xdr.open("post", "https://_url_here");
  xdr.send( post_data );
}else { $.ajax(params); }
```

When I opened an `https` version of the origin site, it successfully sent data to the receiving url, but it couldn't parse any of the data. `xdr.send(post_data);` "looks" like when it's being sent, I wasn't able to find info on that or see it in the console. I looked at [this](http://www.webdbg.com/test/xdm/httptohttps.asp) but couldn't quite get it; console responded: `Unable to get value of the property 'postMessage': object is null or undefined`

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
  var domain = $("iframe").contentWindow;
  domain.postMessage( post_data );
  }else {
    $.ajax(params);
  }
```

Can anyone offer me some help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the script here: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

include it in your html after your link to jquery, but before the script where you are making the ajax call.

in a rather janky way, I used this script to send the request to my app run on heroku (http -> http = works fine), then had a sinatra app running at the heroku site that then sent the data on to the https site. not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Got this to work with IE10. Gonna check with IE9. I know IE10 supports CORS.